# What is this Duplo-like Playmobil bag called?

Tags: part-identification

I bought some random Duplo secondhand and can't figure out what set or name this piece is from/called

[image: mystery toy]

Comment: Are you SURE it's Duplo? It looks like a Playmobil bag in this 1-2-3 set <https://i2.wp.com/canadianmomreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/My-Take-Along-Farm.jpg?resize=768%2C559> but I haven't been able to find one with the same pattern.

Comment: Good point - maybe it isn't Duplo. It came with the big assortment I bought but perhaps a piece from another brand was slipped in

Comment: I'd be interested in what the top and bottom look like.

Comment: @RSchulz you should post that as an answer, since you clearly identified the part.

Answer (score 4):

With thanks to RSchulz,

This is  a Playmobil part

It belongs to : [Playmobil 6774 - Garbage truck](https://www.klickypedia.com/sets/6774-garbage-truck/)

[image: Playmobil 6774 - Garbage truck]

[image: Playmbile 9774 - Inventory]

Comment: Thank you very much for identifying it!

Comment: @SandraNelson remember to click the checkmark to indicate this is the right piece for any future searchers.

Comment: I searched for milk and cow and grapes and yogurt and toothpaste - turns out I should have just searched for garbage bag and it would've popped right up!